# can we store a complext object in http headers webapi

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I have a complex object like the following, i need the client sending this in the headers object, is this possible in webapi or should these properties be sent as name value pairs ??

```
class Employee
{
string firstname;
string lastname;
List<String> Courses;
}
```

Comment: HTTP headers are text; you're showing a class, and you want to send  an instance of that class: an object. So your question is _"How to get a textual representation of an object"_, which is called serialization. So the answer is: yes, if you can serialize it in some way. Which serialization format is most appropriate depends on context; perhaps try JSON? I strongly suggest to rethink your design though: I don't think you need this in information in an HTTP header.

Comment: Sounds rather like an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) here. Perhaps you can explain exactly what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @user504839 Yes you can, there are a lot of ways since you can put whatever key/value pair in your header, you can serialize class as XML. as JSON etc.. , but headers are made to contain only information about the request itself - the metadata, rather then carrying data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTTP is text-based protocol so everything you send must be serialized in some way to text. WebAPI does not provide any direct help with serializing/de-serializing values for headers.

You can create custom Model Binder (starting point - [Parameter Binding in ASP.NET Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api)) to read values from headers. You still would need to serialize it on client side manually (i.e. as Base64 string of binary serialized data).

Notes:

- usually one sends parameters as body of POST request and not in headers. Headers generally used for auxilary information like authentication.
- depending on language dealing with headers may be significantly harder on client side. Most libraries will provide ways to pass parameters as GET/POST, but finding one for passing parameters in headers is unlikely.